# How to access ViewState variable in Client side Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, viewstate

Is this possible to access ViewState variable at Client Side javascript or jquery functions in asp.net web application? If yes then how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**First Solution:**

You can pass any variable from codebehind to client-side using properties.
Define a `Public` propery in codebehind:

**C#:**

```
public int prtPropertyName {
    get { return ViewState("PropertyName"); }
    set { ViewState("PropertyName") = value; }
}
```

**VB:**

```
Public Property prtPropertyName As Integer
    Get
        Return ViewState("PropertyName")
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        ViewState("PropertyName") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

assign a value to the property and then get the value in javascript using this:

```
<% = prtPropertyName  %>
```

**Second Solution:**

Put the ViewState's value in a hidden field and read the hidden field value in client-side:

```
ViewState("viewStateName") = "This is ViewState value"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("hfHiddenFieldID", ViewState("viewStateName"))
```

Javascript:

```
var strValue = document.getElementById("hfHiddenFieldID");
```

**Third Solution:**

This one is not so clear but all `ViewStates` is saved in a hidden field that created by ASP.NET automatically, you can find the field and read data. You can find this fields in source code of page with this name and id: `name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"`.

Comment: Is it not possible to directly use them , the way we use them in server side?

Comment: It's possible but not in a clean way.All `ViewState`s is saved in a hidden field that created by ASP.NET automatically, you can find the field and read data. You can find this fields in source code of page with this name and id: `__VIEWSTATE`.

Comment: No there is no way like server-side one.

Comment: and what about session state variables?

Comment: For sessions just simply use `alert('<% = Session("sessionName") %>');` in VB and `alert('<% = Session["sessionName"] %>');` in C.